# How to add images folders to local wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just starting out with WordPress and trying to create a theme from scratch based on an existing static website I have, all the guides and tutorials I have followed didn't mention anything on how to reference my images folder something like the way I used the enqueue function to add scripts and multiple CSS files.
[Attached is a screenshot of my current file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6lG3.png)

I already tried adding it in the head tag of my header file but none of the images show when I live preview the site, Inspecting element [inspecting element on where an image is supposed to be shows that wordpress can't see the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplMp.png)
How can I add all the images in my folder at once and reference them appropriately when I need to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on where you put the items.  Typically if they are static theme specific images like css images or things that users won't have to access, I would create a folder called `/my-theme/images/image.jpg`

The WordPress way to get the IMG URL is:

`<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>'/images/image.jpg'>`

Comment: The first single quote shouldn't be there and the second one should be a double quote. Useful answer though!

Answer (score 0):

correct code is here:

/images/shumaila.png">